# jquery order <li> in the beginning of the list if it is tagged with special class

Tags: jquery

I have this beautiful jquery script that takes list of `li`s and groups them under `ul` 4 `li` each.

But some of the `li`s have a special class: `<li class="prefslidefeatured">`

I want this special li to stay at the top of the list thus in the first ul as first li. There can be several lis tagged featured so I want all of them to stay at the beginning of the list thus first ul.

Is this script I have easily modifiable to accommodate this new feature? Any ideas how to achieve this?

I also made jsfiddle for quick dirty test :) http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/5at2G/

```
//This is for footer slider, it rewrites 1 ul into several uls that contain 4 li max.
$(document).ready(function(){

    // get the container, useful for later too...
    var container = $(".prefooterslides");

    // get all available UL and LI elements...
    var li_elements = container.find("LI").clone();

    // remove the current content so that we can rebuild it for the slider...
    container.find("UL").remove();

    // build the slider container...
    var slide_container = $("<div />");
    slide_container.addClass("slides_container");

    // tricky part: looping through the LI's and building each of the slides...
    // first create some helpful variables...
    var li_elements_per_slide = 4;
    var li_counter = 0;
    // create the first slide, with a UL to hold the LI's...
    var current_li_div = $("<div />");
    current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));

    // loop through the LI's...
    li_elements.each(function(index, element){

        li_counter++;
        var current_li = $(element).clone();
        current_li_div.find("UL").append(current_li);

        if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide == 0)
        {
            // we've hit 4 in this list, so add the slide and make
            // a new one, using same code as before...
            container.append(current_li_div);
            current_li_div = $("<div />");
            current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));
        }

    });

    // we might have an uneven number of LI's, so we need to check for this...
    if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide != 0)
        container.append(current_li_div);

    // all that's left to do is to initialise the slider script...
    $("#prefooterindex").slides({
        container: 'prefooterslides',
        generatePagination: false
    });

});
```

Comment: What if there are more than 4 featured `li`s?

Comment: @MattBradley it would spill into next ul.

Comment: Before the code that clones and removes the `li`s, do a selector on the class you want to be first and `.prepend` them to the ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Change:

```
var li_elements = container.find("LI").clone();
```

to:

```
var li_elements = container.find("LI.prefslidefeatured").clone();
li_elements = li_elements.add(container.find('LI:not(.prefslidefeatured)').clone());
```

It gets all of the featured `li`s first, then adds all of the non-featured `li`s to the end of the array. The `.each()` further down now iterates over the featured items first, meaning they get added to the top-most `ul`s.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5at2G/1/